# SoapClient vary slow

Tags: php, performance, soap

I'm working on get response from anther server "which I don't have any access on it " and we use SoapClient function to get result and its vary slow how  i can speed up the process . specially  when i use like more than 1000 file send it and Waite response it take more then 4 hour.

```
$client = new SoapClient("$service_url/cvx/CVXtractorService.wsdl");
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $targetfile);
        $ext = pathinfo($targetfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($ext == 'zip'){
            $this->ZipArchive($targetfile);
```

how i can speed the process if there any way ???

Comment: If you are using an external server (not yours), it depends on your internet connection & the response of the wsdl

Comment: is there any way to speed up the process like read and process  multi file in the same time

Comment: I must  user threaded  to achieve this